# How to load some accounts with solana-test-ledger?

Tags: solana-test-validator

I'm trying to load account using  `solana-test-validator --account mock.json --ledger test-ledger` but the error was

```
error: Found argument 'test-ledger' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

What is the required argument for --ledger I was trying to use my local test-validator directory?

Also how can I load a set of accounts?

Comment: `solana-test-validator -h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `solana-test-validator -h` will be the most useful command to figure out why it's not working. Here's the relevant info:

```
OPTIONS:
        --account <ADDRESS> <DUMP.JSON>
            Load an account from the provided JSON file (see `solana account --help` on how to dump an account to file).
            Files are searched for relatively to CWD and tests/fixtures. If ADDRESS is omitted via the `-` placeholder,
            the one in the file will be used. If the ledger already exists then this parameter is silently ignored
```

So you need to do `--account <ADDRESS> mock.json` or `--account - mock.json`.

Also, as the help text says: "If the ledger already exists then this parameter is silently ignored", so you may need to reset the ledger with `--reset`.